# bundle sqlite database with app and stringByAppendingPathComponent error

Tags: sqlite, compiler-errors, xcode4.2, bundle

There are probably many other questions I don't even know to ask yet since I'm new to app programming.

I initially created the database from within the app, copied it to my working folder (which is probably not where it should ultimately reside), then appended my records (about 1,000 of them) from a text file.

The first two questions that come to mind are:
- what folder should the database be in?
- how does it get deployed with the app?

I found quite few examples using the following lines in persistentStoreCoordinator function:

```
NSString *storePath = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"myDatabase.sqlite"];
NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:storePath];
```

But the first line gives me the pre-compile error: "Receiver type 'NSURL' for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'stringByAppendingPathComponent:'.  Why is it not working for me?

And is this in fact the best way to bundle my database with the rest of the app?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002250/importing-sqlite-to-coredata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest solution is to use NSUrl instead of NSString. SO user @trapper already provided a solution in the below link.

[importing sqlite to coredata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002250/importing-sqlite-to-coredata)

```
NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Database.sqlite"];

// If the database doesn't exist copy in the default one
if (![storeURL checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:NULL])
{
    NSURL *defaultStoreURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Database" withExtension:@"sqlite"];

    if ([defaultStoreURL checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:NULL])
    {
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        [fileManager copyItemAtURL:defaultStoreURL toURL:storeURL error:NULL];
    }
}
```